# How to force white text on a black background in Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer

In Internet Explorer, how can I convert lengthy white background pages into a page with black background and white letters (just like in the image below)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily IE on windows phone supports [bookmarklets](http://pokiapp.com/bookmarklet), and this one can do that

```
javascript:(function(){var newSS,styles='*{background:black !important;color:#fff !important}:link,:link *{color:#9ef !important}:visited,:visited *{color:#e9f !important}';newSS=document.createElement('link');newSS.rel='stylesheet';newSS.href='data:text/css,'+escape(styles);document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newSS);})();
```

[image]

(source adapted from [webpage](http://great-grandma.com/bookmarklet/darken-rev_zzr.html))

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Windows Phone 8.1, IE supports a feature called Reading View which presents a stripped-down, text-centric version of the webpage you're viewing, and can optionally be configured to show white text on a black background.

To activate Reading View, tap the book icon in the IE address bar when it shows up. Note, however, that this icon does not show up on every page. I'm not sure what exactly triggers it (amount of text on the page?), and there doesn't seem to be any way to force it either.

To configure Reading View to show white text on a black background, expand the IE app bar (tap the "..." icon next to the address bar) and go to Settings → Advanced settings. From there, set "Reading view style" to "dark". If you want, you can also change the font size right there.

Example result:

[image]

For more information about Reading View, see this article by Paul Thurrott:
[Windows Phone 8.1 Tip: Use Reading View in IE 11](http://winsupersite.com/windows-phone/windows-phone-81-tip-use-reading-view-ie-11)

Comment: Yes, that is a new feature of 8.1; but I'm not sure if reader mode can be used for any page?

Comment: @mpapec Indeed, that's the main downside of this feature. However, when the button does show up, it works very well.